# Cannot use stats.js with three.js

Tags: three.js

I want to see the fps

[my code pen](https://codepen.io/Rudrak-Patra/pen/OJpeNaa)
(THE CODE PEN IS EDITED AND IS WORKING CORRECTLY)

I followed
[this](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/web_development/9781783981182/1/ch01lvl1sec15/determining-the-frame-rate-for-your-scene)
tutorial in packtpub.com

I also followed the instructions in [github repo](https://github.com/mrdoob/stats.js/#usage)

I also tried npm install though code pen npm installer
which gave me this line
import installStats from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/install-stats@1.0.6";

**relevent code**

```
import installStats from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/install-stats@1.0.6";
var stats = new Stats();
stats.showPanel( 0 ); // 0: fps, 1: ms, 2: mb, 3+: custom
document.body.appendChild( stats.dom );
```

.....

```
const clock = new THREE.Clock();
const tick = () => {
  // stats.begin();

  const elapsedTime = clock.getElapsedTime();

  // Update controls
  controls.update();

  // Update time
  waterMaterial.uniforms.uTime.value = elapsedTime;
  // Render
  renderer.render(scene, camera);

  // stats.end();
  // Call tick again on the next frame
  window.requestAnimationFrame(tick);
};

tick();
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that changing the stats cdn version from r17 to r16 can make it work.

use

`https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/stats.js/r16/Stats.min.js`

instead of

`https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/stats.js/r17/Stats.min.js`

and I also got rid of this line

```
import installStats from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/install-stats@1.0.6";
```

Comment: I followed your instruction but there is problem with document.body.appendChild(stats.dom);

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'. 
 at https://cdpn.io/cp/internal/boomboom/pen.js?key=pen.js-777027f3-1742-83fe-cc34-7e590904a741:6

Comment: It would be a great help if you link  here where you test the scene

Comment: it should be `stats.domElement` instead of `stats.dom`

Comment: thanks you very much ,  It is working now!